# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка протокола. Установление сессии не удалось

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Настраиваю проект для работы с PostgreSQL. Проект на Spring 5, Hibernate 5.

База по настройкам подключается, Connect Successfull.

Конфигурационный файл БД следующий:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.example.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:/properties/postgresql.properties")
public class TransactionManagerConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ru.example.entity");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/database");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Стектрейс:

```
дек 08, 2017 1:55:46 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ошибка протокола.  Установление сессии не удалось.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:622)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

Я пока вбил настройки в бин Datasource, это,понятно, временно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На порту 3306 обычно находится mysql. Проверьте его.
Postgres по умолчанию работает на 5432

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.